# jQuery sortable on dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am having issues when adding a new sortable element dynamically to the DOM.

I setup my sortable the following way:

```
$(".lesson_field, #custom_words").sortable({
    connectWith: ".lesson_field, #custom_words",
});
```

}

But, when I add a new lesson_field class, it does not behave like a sortable element.

I tried destroying sortable, by using "destroy", and re-initalizing, but that does not work. I also tried using "refresh" and "refreshPosition"

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rz2mh8ec/6/ (press "Add" to reproduce issue)

Thanks

Comment: One thing that looks wrong is the fact that you have multiple fieldsets  with the same id. Also, I don't see what is sortable. How do you sort?

Comment: Just noticed as well, I fixed that (and updated the fiddle link), and it's still reproducing. I am just using "sortable" to re-order elements.

Comment: I see, it didn't work on my phone. Orderable would be a more intuitive name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `.clone()` on an element that has its own `id` attribute, You're duplicating this `id` what is not good practice.
<s>Next thing is that `sortable` should be applied on the parent element.</s>

---

**EDIT**

Seems that the problem is with `clone(true)`.
It doest work when events handlers are not copied along with the element (`.clone(false)`)

You have to `destroy` sortable before you attempt to `clone(true)`:

```
var lessons = 2

function sort() {
    $(".lesson_field, #custom_words").sortable({
        connectWith: ".lesson_field, #custom_words",
    });
}

window.addanother = function () {
    // destroy sortable:
    $(".lesson_field, #custom_words").sortable("destroy");
    // then clone the element:
    var e = $("#lesson_1").first().clone(true)
    e.attr("id", "lesson_" + lessons)
    lessons++;
    e.insertAfter($("#lesson_1").last())
    sort();
}

sort();
```

<s>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6w5h0zxe/)</s> [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c8w1kwr0/)

Comment: This is not what I am trying to achieve, I want to reorder/move the ".entry" divs

Comment: This is simply amazing. I was banging my head for last 2 days. Finally in console in Chrome, I understood, it was still sorting the 'original' table only (which is template and hence hidden in my case)... Thanks a ton man